# Redirect AMP pages to non amp only for users using NGINX

Tags: seo, nginx, amp

We have a huge news website, with more than 10.000.000 views for month.

We have amp pages, and now every indexed content in the google mobile serp is AMP.
Basically only direct views go to the mobile version, the organic search go to the amp.

Amp are without comments, less advertising. We want to revert back, but I don't want to risk our rank.
Do you think is possible to redirect, with NGINX, real users to the "non amp" pages when they click on the amp links.

So basically:

Google Bots -> AMP pages, with a filter on nginx
Users -> they click on the amp link on google, and then they are redirected to the non amp version

Any issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en): showing one page to Googlebot and another to users.

Google does not like deceptive practices like cloaking.  Google will penalize sites that don't show Googlebot the same thing they show to users.

If you want to redirect to AMP, you should do so for both users and Googlebot.

Comment: Ok so i have to redirect both, and then remove the amp and update the index?

Comment: Google will automatically update their index as Googlebot finds the redirects.   At most you should change all links on your site to the mobile version, including those in your sitemap.